# How to choose a diode and adapt a charging circuit so it can sense temperature from two battery stacks instead of one?

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, ohms-law, thermistor

I have two questions regarding the schematic below.

Diode D3 (D2 in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/DS2715-3122641.pdf)) at location A3-A4 is not defined in the datasheet. R9 (R2 in the example) is sized at: 220Ω. The input voltage is 9V. The operating current is 150µA.

The datasheet gives this guidance:

> D1 prevents current from flowing into the charge source. D2 and R2
> create the maintenance charge current path. D1, D2 and R2 should be
> sized appropriately for the wattage they must dissipate based on the
> application parameters.

Would $$ P=V^2/R $$ be the correct way to calculate the wattage?

The second question is:

There are two thermistors (one for each battery pack) that are used to determine charge state via battery temperature. They can be found on the schematic at location C5-C6. Problem is the datasheet example only uses a single battery stack and I have two. The way I wired it I'm sure will not work. What can be done to adapt this part of the circuit to work with two thermistors?

[image]

Comment: Is a thermistor built into each battery pack or can you fix them together and use one thermistor?

Comment: The other issue you have is that the values of some of the resistors are calculated based on three cells. You will need to recalculate if you're using six cells.

Comment: @Finbarr The two battery stacks are separated by about  4 inches. I am designing the assembly that the stack is part of and to get the best measurement, I feel the thermistor should be only an air gap away from the batteries.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that R11 was off. I have changed it to 500kΩ.

Comment: You'll probably need to change R9 as well although it's probably not critical. And no, you can't just put the thermistors in parallel like that as the combined resistance will be proportional to the average temperature of both packs. One can overheat while the other doesn't.